C# - Looking for an efficient way to add a range of numbers to a collection only replacing null elements
I would like to add a range of numbers to a collection but only replacing null elements.  True would be returned if elements have been replaced, otherwise false.
For example let's say I have a collection with 6 elements that are all null
var collection = { null, null, null, null, null, null };

Then consider I have the following range of values
var a = { 2, 3, 4 };
var b = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var c = { 4, 5 };

I would like to add them to the collection in an efficient manner such that only the free slots are assigned the new values.
So if I were to add the range of numbers from a
var canAdd = collection.AddRange(a);

then canAdd would be true and the collection would look like
{ null, null, 2, 3, 4, null }

Adding the range from b would also return true and the collection would now look like
{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }

Adding the range from c would be false as there are no free slots remaining.
Now I understand that this is the sort of thing sets are useful for.  However, the range of numbers I want to add would be dynamic and determined by the XMin and XMax properties of a separate class.  I would also like to avoid the following

Iterating over the dynamic range of numbers from XMin to XMax
Iterating over the collection for free slots

Is this possible with any of the data structures provided by C# (.NET libraries)?

so, it's supposed to be ordered in ascending order?

In this case the numbers will span a range of min to max denoted by X1 and X2. I need to know if any of that range doesn’t exist and return true if so, otherwise false.
